# Passing space separated string as argument from Java Code to execute a Python Code

Tags: java, python, io-redirection

I have a file **try.java** which has the following code. I have a space-separated string which I should pass as an argument to execute another python code `test.py`. Is there any easier way to access the whole string as a single argument rather than to iterate through every argument using
`sys.argv[1]` in python code to get all the arguments as one string? Currently, I am doing this...

#### test.py

```python
import sys
lst = [' {0} '.format(elem) for elem in sys.argv[1:]]
str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in lst)
print(str1)
```

#### try.java

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Try{
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            String s = "space separated string";
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 test.py " + s);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
           String ret = (in.readLine());
            System.out.println("value is : " + ret);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Any explanation with some Reference would be helpful.

Comment: did you try adding quotes around your string ? something like this in your code - String s = "\"space separated string\"";

Comment: @Chandan Yes I did, but it didn't work.